# How to read multiple texts files, where we read all text files only of same group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I have several text files in my directory like this,

```py
id-2020-01-21-22.txt
id-2020-01-21-23.txt
id-2020-01-22-00.txt
id-2020-01-22-01.txt
id-2020-01-22-02.txt
id-2020-01-23-00.txt
id-2020-01-24-00.txt
```

So how can i read them like where I read `id-2020-01-21-22.txt` & `id-2020-01-21-23.txt` together first, make them into a data frame, write them to a combined text file, then `id-2020-01-22-00.txt` & `id-2020-01-22-01.txt` & `id-2020-01-22-02.txt` all together, write them to a dataframe and so on until the last file in the directory.

inner structure of all the text file looks like so:

```py
100232323\n
903812398\n
284934289\n
{empty line placeholder}
```

No heading, but each text file has an empty line at the end. I am new to python, appreciate if you can help  me out.

This is how far I have gotten:

```py
import os

new_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./textFilesFolder'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as f:
                text = f.read()
                new_list.append(text)


print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want daily summaries where you catenate the hourly files together.
Ok, good.

Create a Y-m-d date [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

date_re = re.compile(r'^id-(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-\d{2}\.txt$')
prev_date = None
```

Now in your loop you can replace the existing `if` with:

```
        m = date_re.search(file)
        if m:
            date = m.group(1)
            print(f'Working on day {date} ...')
            ...
            prev_date = date
```

Having parsed out the date, you can now notice when it changes,
perhaps by comparing whether `prev_date == date`,
and take appropriate action, like writing out to a new file.

Or consider using `with open(f'output-{date}.txt', 'a') as fout:`
to let you append to a (potentially already existing) file.
That way the filesystem is remembering things for you,
rather than needing to keep track of more variables in your program.

BTW, your use of `walk()` is perfectly nice, kudos on that.
But for this directory of files, the structure is simple enough
that you could use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```
new_list = []
for file in glob.glob('id-*.txt'):
    ...
```

EDIT

Suppose we start with a clear slate, no output files:

```
$ rm output-*.txt
```

Then we could just append in a loop, similar to `$ cat hour01 hour02 > day31`.
Or, same thing, similar to `$ rm day31; cat hour01 >> day31; cat hour02 >> day31`.

```
        m = date_re.search(file)
        if m:
            date = m.group(1)
            print(f'Working on day {date} ...')
            with open(file) as fin:
                with open(f'output-{date}.txt', 'a') as fout:
                    fout.write(fin.read())
```

And that's it, you're done! We read the hourly text, and
write it to the end of the daily file.

I mentioned the `rm` above because, if you're debugging and you run
this twice or N times, you'll wind up with an output file N times bigger
than you were hoping for.

Comment: Thank you sir. I don't follow you properly. Sorry about the question. I have the files already. I just have to read them where I read all of the 2020-01-21 text files together, and make one single 2020-01-21 text file that combines all the 2020-01-21 chunks that got read. Should your code go inside my loop??

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you mean now. Gotcha!! Thank you boss :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to do it like this for readability.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import os
import pandas as pd

data = defaultdict(list)
for i in (os.listdir('files/')): # here files is a folder in current directory.
    print(i)                     # which has your text files.
    column = i.split('-')[3]
    with open('files/'+i, 'r') as f:
        file_data = f.read().replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')
        data[column].extend(file_data[:-1])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print('---')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
id-2020-01-22-01.txt
id-2020-01-22-00.txt
id-2020-01-21-23.txt
id-2020-01-21-22.txt
---
          22          21
0    1006523  1002323212
1   90381122  9038123912
2   28493423   284934212
3  100232323   100232323
4  903812332   903812392
5  284934212   284934289
```

Comment: Thank you shivank, I would have picked this as an answer. However J_H answered it first. But thanks a million for your help dude!

Comment: @WannabeSmith Totally no issue :)